# I get this error Error: Unknown command: cask any ideas?

Tags: macos, nativescript, apple-m1

putting the command '***brew cask install adoptopenjdk8***' gives me that error, any ideas?

Error: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps:
homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8

in Mac M1...

Comment: Have you previously been able to install using homebrew and cask? If you're new to both/either, you might still need to install cask separately using `brew install cask` if you have homebrew installed. See [here](https://cask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/installation.html) for more info on installing cask.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- `brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk` first
- then `brew install --cask <version you want>`

the `tap` allows you to stay with the release you want. Also, your command above may not work because AdoptOpenJDK8 isn't the latest version